# Unable to delete Umbraco member type from backend

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I've installed the Dialogue forum plug in for Umbraco. I've got this set up and working just fine. I'm able to create new members both via the forum itself and through code.

However, when I come to manually deleting them from my CMS backend, I get an error telling me I need to contact my admin (me) and to check the log.

Checking the log I found this:

```
2015-01-19 09:21:19,090 [5] ERROR System.Web.IHtmlString - [Thread 15] Dialogue Package: Error trying to delete Dialogue member
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.MemberService.RefreshMemberPosts(Member member, Int32 amount)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.PostService.SyncMembersPostCount(List`1 members)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.PostService.Delete(Post post)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.MemberService.DeleteAllAssociatedMemberInfo(Int32 userId, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)

2015-01-19 09:21:19,095 [5] ERROR System.Web.IHtmlString - [Thread 24] Dialogue Package: Error trying to delete Dialogue member
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.MemberService.RefreshMemberPosts(Member member, Int32 amount)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.PostService.SyncMembersPostCount(List`1 members)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.PostService.Delete(Post post)
   at Dialogue.Logic.Services.MemberService.DeleteAllAssociatedMemberInfo(Int32 userId, UnitOfWork unitOfWork)


2015-01-19 09:21:19,110 [5] WARN  System.Web.IHtmlString - [Thread 15] Dialogue Package: There was an error attemping to delete member barry scott and all of their associated data (Posts, Topics etc...)
2015-01-19 09:21:19,131 [5] WARN  System.Web.IHtmlString - [Thread 24] Dialogue Package: There was an error attemping to delete member bryanredban and all of their associated data (Posts, Topics etc...)
2015-01-19 09:22:07,960 [5] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing - [Thread 8] An error occurred with the scheduled publishing
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing.Run()
```

Whilst I get the general idea that my backend can't find the member, I'm really stumped as to how it's able to create one. I mean, if it can create a member, it should be able to delete one as well.

I can still delete normal umbraco members as I please. I've even tried uninstalling dialogue and re installing but I get the same issue. I've even gone into my server and deleted every single database that dialogue creates but the issue still persists.

Has anyone ever had this issue before? Is there something someone could recommend that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug too me.  I would try posting this on 
the Dialogue forum: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/dialogue/general